# Emmeans including interaction that shouldn't exist?

Tags: lme4, emmeans

I have a data set that has three between-participant groups and one dependent variable.

I created a dummy coded column for Groups 2 and 3, such that Group 1 is the reference group.

I then fit a model with lme4 (DV ~ Group 2 + Group 3). Of course, there can be no interaction between Groups 2 and 3, as these are mutually exclusive.

However, I when I used the emmeans package to get the marginal means of the groups, it shows marginal means for an interaction between Groups 2 and 3 (that is, means for when a person belongs to both).

How can I deal with this?

Below is a small reproducible code with fictitious data.

```
## call packages
require(lme4)
library(emmeans)

## Create data frame (df) with two between-participant groups dummy coded; DV = dependent variable
Group2 <- c(0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0)
Group3 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1)
DV <- c(1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6, 7)
df <- data.frame(Group2, Group3, DV)
print (df)

## define dummy code levels (0,1) as factors
df$Group2<-as.factor(df$Group2)
df$Group3<-as.factor(df$Group3)

## fit model
Model01 <- glm(DV ~ Group2+Group3, data=df)
Model01

## extract estimated marginal means
Model01em <- emmeans(Model01, ~ Group2 + Group3, nesting = NULL)
Model01em
```

Why does emmeans include an interaction that doesn't exist in the model?

I cannot find any documentation about this issue or any similar thread.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, `emmeans` treats the two predictors `Group2` and `Group3` as *separate predictors*.

To use `emmeans` correctly for your example, do:

```
df$Group <- factor(rep(1:3, each = 6))
mod <- lm(DV ~ Group, data = df)
emmeans(mod, pairwise ~ Group)
```

We hardly ever need to use dummy coding to fit models. R (and most other statistical software these days) is quite capable of creating the dummies it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar confusion when dealing with examples with missing data, and [this documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/basics.html) really helped me understand, specifically the portion about the **reference grid** and the emphasis on:

> the analysis obtained is really an analysis of the model, not the data

As mentioned by @Russ Lenth, the two predictors are treated as separate, and so have separate estimates.  It does not matter that the combination `Group2 == 1 & Group3 == 1` does not exist in the data, `emmeans` analyzes the *model*, which does have estimates for the effect of `Group2 == 1`, as well as `Group3 == 1` and can use these to predict the response for a sample where both are 1.

This sample comes from the reference grid, which, adapting the documentation to your example, would be:

`expand.grid(Group2 = unique(Group2), Group3 = unique(Group3))`

which includes the non-existent level.